# Why a:hover didn't on jquery

Tags: jquery

why a:hover didn't on jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#leftmenu ul li.active ul li a").css( "background-color","#4a4647" );  <--it work
$("#leftmenu ul li.active ul li a:hover").css( "background-color","#d3d4d6" );  <--didn't work

});
```

Comment: you should just use normal CSS for this.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery uses selectors to select elements only.

Use the [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method instead, or just use CSS.

```
$("#leftmenu ul li.active ul li a").hover(function() {
    $(this).css( "background-color","#d3d4d6" );
}, function() {
    $(this).css( "background-color","#4a4647" );
});
```

This should **definitely** be something you do in CSS, however. You should try to minimise leaking presentational information (the `background-color`) into the behavioural layer.

Comment: Thank you! it works.And I have another question, how can I change css only on the ul li,not ul li ul li when using jquery??

Comment: @user964351: If you have another [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)...

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be changed to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#leftmenu ul li.active ul li a").hover(function() {
     $(this).css( "background-color","#d3d4d6" );    
  }, function() {
      $(this).css( "background-color","#4a4647" );
  });
});
```